# Check if a bitmask consists of multiple flags

Tags: .net, bitwise-operators

Note, this is not a dupe of this question:

[Testing if a bitmask has one and only one flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807995/testing-if-a-bitmask-has-one-and-only-one-flag)

I need to validate whether or not a bitmask consists of multiple flags.  I've come up with this method, but I don't like it a whole lot because of the enumeration and casting.

```
[Flags]
enum MyFlags { a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8 }

var flags = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyFlags)).Cast<MyFlags>();

Console.WriteLine(flags.Any(f => f == (MyFlags.a | MyFlags.c))); //false
Console.WriteLine(flags.Any(f => f == MyFlags.b)); //true
```

Comment: Might be clearer with your example if you made clear what the input/value under test is. I assume it's where you've currently got literal expressions, but it's presumably a `MyFlags` parameter/variable that has already been set? Also, not entirely sure what you're expecting if you're working with an enum which has named combinations (e.g. [FileShare.ReadWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: If it's literally just "this value has more than a single bit set" then what you're looking for would seem to be a `population count`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to test if a bitmask consist of flags, you can do it like this

```
MyFlags flag = MyFlags.b | MyFlags.d | MyFlags.a;

Console.WriteLine(flag.HasFlag(MyFlags.b));             // true
Console.WriteLine(flag.HasFlag(MyFlags.a | MyFlags.b)); // true
Console.WriteLine(flag.HasFlag(MyFlags.c | MyFlags.b)); // false
```

**Edit**
You can also have a look at the `BitArray` class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically you just have to count the number of bit set to one in the `BitArray`

You can use this fast `GetCardinality` method to count them (alternatively, you can also do it with a for loop): [Counting bits set in a .Net BitArray Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063178/counting-bits-set-in-a-net-bitarray-class). Then:

```
public static bool HasExactlyOneBitSet(Enum e)
{
    return GetCardinality(new BitArray(new[] { (int)(object)e })) == 1;
}
```

And you will use it like this:

```
HasExactlyOneBitSet(MyFlags.A);             // true
HasExactlyOneBitSet(MyFlags.A | MyFlags.C); // false
```

Comment: This is not what I want to do.  This checks if a bitmask consists of specific set flags.  I want to ensure that the bitmask passed in consists of a single flag in the available set of flags.  I also won't know the enum type, so it has to be dynamic like in my OP example.  Lastly, HasFlags is evil and you should not use it.

Comment: Ho okay, I just edited my answer...